# What is journey?

Tags: teaching

In the sentence: "There was no guarantee that the travelers would survive the journey."

Would "the journey" be considered a direct object, or what would it be?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "the journey" would indeed be considered a direct object. Note that [Merriam-Webster lists](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survive) three transitive uses of "survive," with the second being relevant to this case. Similar examples include:

> He lived his life.

"Lived" can be used intransitively, without "life," or transitively, as it is here.

> She won the contest.

Similarly, "the contest"  is an object here, although "won" can be used intransitively to refer to the same event.